# Python/bs4: Span inside div tag - text extraction

Tags: python, html, tags, beautifulsoup

I'm beating with an text extraction from div tag. The point is that there is a  tag without opening pair, inside the div tag. So if I do this: `raw = soup.find('div', class_='inside').text` 
I get only text before the  tag.

An example:

```
<div class='inside'><div>sth0</div><div>sth1</div></span><div>sth2<div></div>

soup.find('div', class_='inside').text

>>> sth0  sth1
```

Do you have an idea how to get a whole text from div tag? Thanks

EDIT (According to  Tanmaya Meher, the code above should work, but for me doesn't so I'm attaching the exact problem

When I run this code:

```
raw = firmHtml.find('div', class_='inside').text
print raw
```

I get

```
Katalóg   Obchody a veľkoobchod
```

Instead of:

```
Katalóg   Obchody a veľkoobchod   Stavebniny   Izolačný materiál...
```

Here is a cut from my code.

`<div class="inside"><div class="inside2"><a  href="/katalog/" style="font-size:12px"  title="Katalóg"><span>Katalóg</span></a> <span class="sipka s1">&nbsp;</span> <a  href="/katalog/obchody-a-velkoobchod/" style="font-size:12px"  itemprop="url"  title="Obchody a veľkoobchod"><span itemprop="title" >Obchody a veľkoobchod</span></a></span> <span class="sipka s1">&nbsp;</span> <span itemprop="child"  itemscope itemtype="http://data-vocabulary.org/Breadcrumb" ><a  href="/katalog/stavebniny_1/" style="font-size:12px"  itemprop="url"  title="Stavebniny"><span itemprop="title" >Stavebniny</span></a></span> <span class="sipka s1">&nbsp;</span> <span itemprop="child"  itemscope itemtype="http://data-vocabulary.org/Breadcrumb" ><a  href="/katalog/izolacny-material/" style="font-size:12px"  itemprop="url"  title="Izolačný materiál"><span itemprop="title" >Izolačný materiál</span></a></span> <span class="sipka s1">&nbsp;</span> <span itemprop="child"  itemscope itemtype="http://data-vocabulary.org/Breadcrumb" ><a  href="/katalog/protipoziarne-izolacie/" style="font-size:12px"  itemprop="url"  title="Protipožiarne izolácie"><span itemprop="title" >Protipožiarne izolácie</span></a></span> <span class="sipka s1">&nbsp;</span> Ing. Milan Kalafut</div></div></div><div id="main"><div id="content"><div  itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/LocalBusiness"  class="business-container"><div id="lavy"><div class="foto s3"><img src="http://s.aimg.sk/katalog/css/images/nologo.gif" alt="Logo nieje k dispozícii" /></div><div id="moznosti">`

Maybe I can't see something.

Comment: I am getting complete `sth0sth1sth2` in both python 2.7 and python 3.3 !!

Comment: @TanmayaMeher Thanks for answer. I've attached the main part of my problem to my question now.

Comment: Now that might be problem with parser. Check this http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#installing-a-parser and try to use different parsers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as BS

html_text = '<div class="inside"><div class="inside2"><a  href="/katalog/" style="font-size:12px"  title="Katalóg"><span>Katalóg</span></a> <span class="sipka s1">&nbsp;</span> <a  href="/katalog/obchody-a-velkoobchod/" style="font-size:12px"  itemprop="url"  title="Obchody a veľkoobchod"><span itemprop="title" >Obchody a veľkoobchod</span></a></span> <span class="sipka s1">&nbsp;</span> <span itemprop="child"  itemscope itemtype="http://data-vocabulary.org/Breadcrumb" ><a  href="/katalog/stavebniny_1/" style="font-size:12px"  itemprop="url"  title="Stavebniny"><span itemprop="title" >Stavebniny</span></a></span> <span class="sipka s1">&nbsp;</span> <span itemprop="child"  itemscope itemtype="http://data-vocabulary.org/Breadcrumb" ><a  href="/katalog/izolacny-material/" style="font-size:12px"  itemprop="url"  title="Izolačný materiál"><span itemprop="title" >Izolačný materiál</span></a></span> <span class="sipka s1">&nbsp;</span> <span itemprop="child"  itemscope itemtype="http://data-vocabulary.org/Breadcrumb" ><a  href="/katalog/protipoziarne-izolacie/" style="font-size:12px"  itemprop="url"  title="Protipožiarne izolácie"><span itemprop="title" >Protipožiarne izolácie</span></a></span> <span class="sipka s1">&nbsp;</span> Ing. Milan Kalafut</div></div></div><div id="main"><div id="content"><div  itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/LocalBusiness"  class="business-container"><div id="lavy"><div class="foto s3"><img src="http://s.aimg.sk/katalog/css/images/nologo.gif" alt="Logo nieje k dispozícii" /></div><div id="moznosti">'

#html_text = open("a.html",'r').read() #I have commented this, you can do like this too; a.html file contains the same html code as above

firmHtml = BS(html_text)
raw = firmHtml.find('div', class_='inside').text

print (raw)
```

Output (with both Python 2.7.5 and Python 3.3.2 on Linux):

```
Katalóg   Obchody a veľkoobchod   Stavebniny   Izolačný materiál   Protipožiarne izolácie   Ing. Milan Kalafut
```